# Exclude packages already contained in compileOnly dependency with gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jar, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm looking for some automatic/simple way to exclude all dependencies from the final jar if they are already contained in any of compile-only depenceny which isn't present in the final jar but is loaded externally. I'm using kotlin DSL for gradle configuration.

my current jar configuration:

```
withType<Jar> {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    archiveClassifier.set("core")

    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })
    exclude(
            "kotlin/**"
    )
}
```

For example I implement jackson yaml format which uses snake YAML as a dependency. However snake YAML is also present in one compileOnly dependency and shouldn't be contained in the final JAR.

If I understand it correctly runtimeClasspath contains only implementation dependencies, but also all of their dependencies, which is the problem

Answer (score 1):

you can have a custom task to create the list of jars you want to package, below snippet show the runtime-compileonly

```
task runCP() {
    def runList = configurations.runtimeClasspath.asList()
    def compileOnlyList = configurations.compileOnly.asList()
    println(runList.join("\n"))
    println("----")
    println(compileOnlyList.join("\n"))
    println("====")
    println(runList.size() + " | " + runList.removeAll(compileOnlyList) + " | " + runList.size())
    println(runList.join("\n"))
}
```